# IntelliJ ignore gradle dependency scopes

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have a gradle build script with about 20 dependencies. Half of them are of scope "shadow" that comes with the shadow plugin. This scope is considered as "runtime" in IntelliJ (which makes sense so far, since the shadow dependencies will not be included into the "fat-jar" created by the shadow plugin, since they are considered provided at runtime).

The problem is, that I have them provided when the finished artifact is deployed in production, but the development environment is different: Here, I need the dependencies actually included into the build (I get a ClassNotFoundError).

How can I tell IntelliJ to ignore the gradle scopes?

Comment: runtime dependencies **are** by definition, available at runtime. What are you doing, and what happens precisely?

Comment: The dependencies are only available at runtime when the artifact is deployed in production. To do that, I run shadowJar (the task of the shadow plugin) and the finished jar contains only the dependencies that are definitelly not provided at runtime. But inside my development environment (controlled by IntelliJ) the "shadow" dependencies are not provided by the environment

Comment: You said they are considered by IntelliJ as runtime dependencies. So they should be available at runtime, when you do what you're doing (what?) with IntelliJ.

Comment: Yes but they are NOT available at runtime, when built with IntelliJ, only when build with gradle and then deployed manually. So that is why I want IntelliJ NOT TO CONSIDER them as runtime dependencies ignoring gradle.

Comment: You still haven't answered my questions. What are you doing with IntelliJ? When are you getting this exception? Why do you thing runtime dependencies are not available at runtime? And what other kind of scope would make them available at runtime?

Comment: I have answered it three times now. Within IntelliJ the overall project configuration is different than in production. This is, because in production, the project artifact is launched via another application, that provides the dependencies. Within development (=within IntelliJ) there is no other application that provides anything, therefore IntelliJ has to provide my dependencies itself. But I do not want to configure gradle to also include the dependencies. Btw I have worked around it by explicitely excluding the dependencies while marking them as "compile" dependencies.